# Unterminated string literal '\'

Tags: python

I Don't know What To Do.The Error Show is undetermined string literal at line (4).Pls Help

```````````
print("      |``````````|  |~~~~")
print("         |    |     |     ~")
print("         |    |     |~~~~")
print("         |    |     | \")
print("         |    |     |  \ ")
print("         ~~~~~~     |   \")
```````````

Comment: Learn about [escape sequences](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals)!

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-format-text-in-python-3 you can find more about escape sequence here

Answer (score 2):

The backslash is special in python strings. If you want to include them literally, you need to escape them by doubling them:

```````````
print("      |``````````|  |~~~~")
print("         |    |     |     ~")
print("         |    |     |~~~~")
print("         |    |     | \\")
print("         |    |     |  \\ ")
print("         ~~~~~~     |   \\")
```````````

Comment: Or you can also add an `r` before opening quotes